# Shuffling/Randomizing a MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to restructure an existing MongoDB collection so that it is "shuffled" or "randomized"?

Comment: The collection's order isn't typically meaningful and will change non-deterministically as updates are made. What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: I'm uploading data into the database on a daily basis.  For the best user experience, I need the data to be randomly organized (but static for the duration of the day). So when I query the database with Collection.find({}), every day, that order needs to be different.

Comment: I would try using aggregation along with some a random generator